# How many neurons are going into each layer of VGG?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

Can you give me a run down of how many neurons are going into each layer. I feel this will improve my understanding of what is going on in VGG.

Let's use this code here just to have something concrete.

https://github.com/machrisaa/tensorflow-vgg/blob/master/vgg19.py#L46

In this line, I see 224x224x3 (an image) being fed in. After each of the lines in the code (each line represents a layer) what happens to the dimension of this image?

thank you.

Comment: Kindly don't downvote without explaining yourself. Also easy with the downvotes.

Comment: I'm just not sure it's really a tensorflow question.  It just sounds like a general machine learning question such that you want to go over the original paper of VGG16.  I didn't downvote btw.

Comment: (this is on the border of machine learning and TF. Btw aren't machine learning questions allowed in SO? If not and if you have admin access, kindly transfer this question to cross validated. But I am worried those folks will complain that this is a SO question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to instrument the code, and got out the sizes for each layer. This gives me a lot of clarity now. I used the interactive session feature in tensorflow to get this done if you are curious.

conv1_1
[100, 224, 224, 64]

conv1_2
[100, 224, 224, 64]

pool1
[100, 112, 112, 64]

conv2_1
[100, 112, 112, 128]

conv2_2
[100, 112, 112, 128]

pool2
[100, 56, 56, 128]

conv3_1
[100, 56, 56, 256]

conv3_2
[100, 56, 56, 256]

conv3_3
[100, 56, 56, 256]

conv3_4
[100, 56, 56, 256]

pool3
[100, 28, 28, 256]

conv4_1
[100, 28, 28, 512]

conv4_2
[100, 28, 28, 512]

conv4_3
[100, 28, 28, 512]

conv4_4
[100, 28, 28, 512]

pool4
[100, 14, 14, 512]

conv5_1
[100, 14, 14, 512]

conv5_2
[100, 14, 14, 512]

conv5_3
[100, 14, 14, 512]

conv5_4
[100, 14, 14, 512]

pool5
[100, 7, 7, 512]

fc6
[100, 4096]

relu6
[100, 4096]

fc7
[100, 4096]

relu7
[100, 4096]

fc8
[100, 1000]

prob
[100, 1000]

Answer (score 2):

The debug information you posted is the dimensions for the outputs of each op/layer. It's related to the number of "neurons", but it is not the same.

### Where do the output dimensions come from?

There's only two types of layers in VGG-19 (excluding softmax and fully connected):

- **Convolutional layers:** they all use 3x3 filters with stride 1 and padding 1. This means the output volume will have the same width and height as the input volume (and depth equal to the number of filters). Slide 44 of the reference below has the formulas for computing output given input dimensions and convolution parameters.
- **Max pool layers:** they all use 2x2 windows with stride 2. This means the output volume will have half the width and half the height of the input volume. Slide 56.

### Where are the neurons?

Say we want to interpret the network as a set of neurons. A neuron being each unit that has a set of weights that it uses to collect a weighted sum of its inputs and then transform with a non-linearity.

First, there are neurons in the fully connected layers: 4096 + 4096 + 1000 = 9192 neurons.

Second there are neurons in the convolutional layers. Basically you can see each filter as one neuron (there's a nice illustration on slide 50).

You can easily lookup the number of filters for each layer on slide 71 (e.g. conv3-64 stands for 64 3x3 filters). For VGG-19 we have 2*64 + 2*128 + 4*256 +  2*4*512 = 5504 neurons.

With all of that said, in practice usually one would measure the size of the network in number of parameters (i.e. weights) and number of layers. VGG-19 has 144 million parameters which is notably large. For comparison the training set has 1.3 million examples.

Reference: http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/winter1516_lecture7.pdf

Comment: I think I meant volume, thanks for correcting my muddled use of volume & neurons interchangeably. Quick question: If you have 64 filters each being a 3x3 operating on an image 224x224x3, shouldn't you have 224x224x(3*64) as the output volume? How does it become 224x224x64?

Comment: Great question. No, each filter application on a single patch of image results in a single number/scalar. See slides 16, 17 and 41. It's also important to note that each filter is as deep as the input. So a 3x3 filter in the first layer of VGG-19 is actually a 3x3x3 (again slide 17).